# Excel chart of arrival times

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, time

I need a chart that shows a carrier's arrival times over a one-month period, and a chart showing arrival times on specific days.  Suggestions?  Three Columns - Date, Day (Mon-Fri), Arrival Time..  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at names ranges or named formula for defining series in graphs.  In terms of graphing there are a variety of graph types you can use.  I am partial to the XY scatter plot.  You talk about names in your question but no evidence of names in your data which is kind of confusing.  Can you extrapolate how "Names" would play into this?

Comment: That was a typo! Specific names = specific days.

Comment: should put your sample data back in your question

Comment: What part of this is the problem?  If you had data limited to what you want to include in the chart, could you do it?

Comment: Not sure which chart to use, or what's best and why.

Comment: lots of different chart types will work.  Do you have multiple arrivals on a single day?  XY chart does a good job of plotting multiple Y values for a single X value

Comment: No.  One arrival time per weekday.  The objective is to determine whether late arrivals occur on certain days and to see the average arrival time over a period of time

Comment: Try making you your column with headers.  Then plot all dates as X series and times as Y series.  Next try applying a filter to your header row and then filter the days to only the days you are interested in and see if they are the only ones that show in the graph.

Comment: Filter works.  But it's displaying the date range wrong.  I don't need April or June in the horizontal axis and the vertical axis should display times from 10:00PM to 3:AM

Comment: select the property of your axis and set the maximum and minimum value you want to have.  Excel will automatically guess a value above and below the limits of your data.  To have specific cut off point you will have to manually enter them on the properties area for each axis.

Comment: How many charts are we looking at..?